# Making a SOAP request by using XML in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby, soap

I want to make a request to a SOAP Web Service but I don't want to install any gems.
Is there any way to just make the request using plain XML?

I think it's trivial but there might be something I've missed, because all implementations/tutorials were using a gem.

I think that the SOAP response, can be handled also as a XML response right?

The request is this:

```
POST /services/tickets/issuer.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: demo.demo.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <Tick xmlns="http://demo.com/test/test">
      <Request>
        <Username>string</Username>
        <Password>string</Password>
        <AcquirerId>int</AcquirerId>
        <RequestType>string</RequestType>
        <ExpirePreauth>unsignedByte</ExpirePreauth>
        <BitPerSec>int</BitPerSec>
        <Office>string</Office>
      </Request>
    </Tick>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do this:

```
def post_xml(path, xml)
  host = "http://demo.demo.com"
  http = Net::HTTP.new(host)
  resp = http.post(path, xml, { 'Content-Type' => 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' })
  return resp.body
end
```

The XML response would be returned by this method.

Comment: Using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.2.12 - I had to remove the "http://" from the host name. Also, using SOAP 1.1 and had to set 'Content-Type' to `text/xml` Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to solve a similar problem and have set up a similar solution. but, the server I am trying to post to requires user authentication. do you have any tips on setting up the credentials?

Comment: What is this `path` variable?