# SOAP request in ruby with authentication/credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, perl, authentication, soap, httprequest

I am trying to send XML/SOAP data to a server using an http POST request, and am starting by converting a working Perl script to Ruby on Rails. Using [some](http://coderberry.me/blog/2008/12/19/creating-custom-soap-requests-with-ruby-and-net-http/) [resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184802/making-a-soap-request-by-using-xml-in-rails), I have written some preliminary code, but I am unsure how to add user authentication (running this code causes a connection timeout error).

My code so far:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(' [host] ', [port])
path = '/rest/of/the/path'
data = [ XML SOAP string ]
headers = {
  'Content-Type' => 'application/atom+xml',
  'Host' => ' [host] '
}
resp, data = http.post(path, data, headers)
```

Adding `http.basic_auth 'user', 'pass'` gave me a no method error

Perl code for supplying credentials:

```
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent(keep_alive=>1);
$ua->credentials($netloc, '', "$user", "$pwd");
...
my $request = POST ($url, Content_Type=> 'application/atom+xml', Content=> $soap_req);
my $response = $ua->request($request);
```

the server uses NTLM, so maybe there is a gem you could recommend ([like this?](http://httpirb.com/#requests)). It looks like the Perl script is using user agents, so I would like to do something similar in Ruby. In summary, how do I add user authentication to my request?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `savon` gem, https://github.com/savonrb/savon?